# How to best search a list of string in java using String.contains?

Tags: java, android, string, search

Right now I'm working on an android application using voice recog. Basically, I'm wondering what the best search method is once I get String from voice recognition. I'm currently using a linear search on the list of packagename, using the following to get that list:

```
    pkgNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    pkgAppsList = (ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>) getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    // List available packages on phone.
    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : pkgAppsList) {

        if (!isSystemPackage(appInfo))
            pkgNames.add(appInfo.packageName);
    }
```

I've decide that it's probably better to use the ApplicationInfo list(pkgAppsList) and do a a search on that, but is there a faster way of searching that list than just a simple linear search and using the result to open the Application with an Intent.
Right now, all I can think of doing is:

```
    for(ApplicationInfo ai: pkgAppsList){
        if((ai.name).contains(voice_recog_result))
           //open Launch Intent for ai.packageName
    }
```

Is there a way faster search method I can use with the contains method or a way I can do this without the contains method?

Comment: Unless you have tens of thousands of installed applications, that will be fast enough, I would think. Calculating the list of installed applications is probably the slowest part, you may want to do that just once on startup and cache the list.

Comment: u want to search from strings ??

Comment: Hmm I guess you're right, I just figured if I wanted to include system applications I might want do something faster than this. And good call on caching, but what would you suggest if they installed something while the up is in use ?

Comment: @Sam_k Maybe you could be more specific, but If i understand what you mean, I'm not really searching from strings as in text input, but the voice recognition conversion is a string list.

Comment: @user986877 okie dear sorry i have no more idea. thanx

Comment: @Sam_k okay, thanks either way

Comment: I have to say i dont really understand what your tring to do... but
what about using a HashMap with appInfo.packageName as key?

retreaving information from HashMap happens in O(1). and it doesnt seem like you can have more than one package with the same name.

Comment: I would go with Thilo's suggestion and not worry about the cost of the linear search for a relatively limited amount of apps. If you really need to keep track of newly installed packages (and then removed ones as well, I presume), you can register your app to receive the PACKAGE_ADDED and PACKAGE_REMOVED intent actions and update the cached list. [See here for an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#7) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For small numbers of searched strings (application names), the simplest method (traversing a linked list) should be chosen.

Auto-growing hash tables are often used for similar tasks, but only if the set of searched strings is often large.  The worst case performance of a hash table is the same as traversing a linked list (due to auto-growing, and due to the potential of mass hash value collisions), and it has non-negligible overhead.  It is therefore not a great choice for "just in case" insurance against a longer set of strings.

The data structure that is *theoretically* fitted to this task is called [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  Tries are not part of JCL or Android libraries, but available implementations [are available](http://code.google.com/p/trie/).  The worst case performance of a trie is proportional to the length of the longest string, regardless of the number of strings.  Tries however tend to take a lot of memory which makes them [unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9247324/1235565) for mobile environments.